# Yii2 redirect and pcntl_fork

Tags: yii2, fork, pcntl

Using Yii2 I have implemented pcntl_fork() in one of my controllers and though the process is working as I need there are a few issues I would like to sort out.

Simplified logic

```
//Start timer marker
Loop(5x) {
 sleep(1);
 $pid = pcntl_fork();

 if(!$pid) {
  //Child Process

  sleep(30);
  //Child process Timer marker 30 seconds
  //processing as expected

 } else if ($pid == -1) {
  //Error

 } else {
  //PARENT

  //Parent timer marker loops 5x 1xloop seconds
 }

}
//Redirect Timer marker at 5 seconds
return $this->redirect(['/account/account-details','accountId'=>Yii::$app->session['accountId']]);
```

By looking at the timer markers my loop is executing every second.
The child process are executing after 30 seconds
31, 32, 33..etc

What is getting me is my redirect is marked at 5 seconds so I know if it hitting that point at 5 seconds.  However the redirect does not execute until after the last child of 35 seconds.  So it seems to hang there. I am guessing I am not using the right pcntl method to continue without waiting for children to finish.

And point in a direction would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: I would rather start by asking: What is the goal you try to achieve? Why are you using `pcntl_fork`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, from a GUI dashboard I am initiating a process that processes several accounts.  Each process take several minutes, so when ran consecutively the dashboard would be hung up until all the processes complete.  So by using the fork I was able to process all accounts concurrently.  It is still a shorter time on the dashboard, waiting for the longest process to complete but not ideal.  I can and have used a console runner in the past but wanted to experiment on getting the fork to work.

Comment: Hey, you might want to look into the following as I think I have successfuly implemented it in some projects: Basically PHP's default behavior is to block new requests until the current one is finished, but! That's because of PHP's session. If you write this before calling a script that takes a long time `\Yii::$app->session->close();` the user will be able to keep navigating to new pages with new browser requests, while that request is still running.

Comment: So one combination would be to put your heavy work on a action that you'll later call from an ajax request so the user doesn't even see that the browser icon shows "loading". Also you should check the PHP time limit so the script won't get killed after 30 seconds.

Comment: So basically, let's say you're on `/dashboard` action, and you have a button that says `Process items`, when you click it, you make an AJAX call to `/process-items` page, where the first thing you put at the beginning of the action is `\Yii::$app->session->close();`. The browser will make the AJAX call, and the user will be able to navigate wherever without having to wait for the request to finish.